# SP2016 - on prem - Doc id does not change

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, document-id

As said in subject SP2016 on prem. Doc library has a list of documents that have flagged approvals or rejections. When I edit the doc, upload same name doc the doc ID never changes. Version will increment but that does not break the relationship for the approval/rejection of the document as the ID itself is associated to that approval.

How do I get the doc id to change when the doc does?

Answer (score 0):

The function of Document ID is to remain the same for the life time of the document and to never change. For example if document A is in library A and you decide to move it to library B, the Document ID will remain the same. The Document ID property is a URL in this format: http:///_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=J2W3DN6QF6XW-2-40. When this URL is clicked, search is used to find the document. This allows the URL to work even if the document has been moved to another location, or renamed.